# Imagen no se muestra a pesar de que esta en la base de datos (PHP / HTML)

Tags: php, html, mysql

esta es una cuestion que me ha dado vueltas por unos dias porque la encuentro bastante ilogica.

Lo que pasa es que tengo un sistema que almacena datos de alumnos, entre ellos la foto. Lo que hago es guardar el nombre de la foto (y la foto enviarla a una carpeta en el servidor xampp), al momento de mostrarlo hago un  que busca la ruta y despues el nombre de la imagen.

El problema es que, tal como se ve en la captura de pantalla, la imagen, aparece como un archivo roto, pero una vez hago click en "inspeccionar elemento", puedo entrar al directorio y efectivamente ver la imagen ahi mismo vivita y coleando.

Este es el codigo que uso para mostrar (en la DB, foto_est es el nombre de la columna donde esta almacenada la foto)

```php
echo "<img src= ../imagenes".$row['foto_est']."> <br>";
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si falta informacion porfavor avisen y edito la pregunta al toque.

Y lamento si la pregunta es muy basica

Comment: esto `echo "<img src= ../imagenes".$row['foto_est']."> <br>"; ` imprime esto `../imagenesmuestra.png` cuando debe ser  `echo "<img src= ./imagenes/".$row['foto_est']."> <br>"; ` hay una opcion e los navegadores dando click derecho inspecionar codigo que te ayuda para futuros errores. saludos!

Comment: Lo revise y me di cuenta de que es lo que pasa...la pagina no guarda nada (revise el codigo y el espacio donde se supone que esta el nombre esta...vacio). De todas formas muchas gracias, ahora se desde donde enfrentar el problema :)